# SQL Server : convert multiple columns into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this

```
name1   name2   name3   value1  value2  value3
  A       B       C        1       2       3
```

I really need this

```
Name    Value
  A       1
  B       2 
  C       3
```

Help me, please.

Comment: [Unpivot](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html) is your friend

Comment: @AlexB.If unpivot is his friend in this instance I urge you to show an example because the reality is the data is double pivoted and unpivoting once will get you names into rows but still have 3 values columns unpivoting a second time will give you every combination of name to value (9).  In this instance UNION all or inserting to a temp table or table variable will be the most straight forward even though I can still think of a way to do it using 2 levels of unpivot and then conditional agregation.

Comment: I have tried using the pivot.. guiding me similar cases but they were not the same case as I have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use union

```
 select name1 as Name, value1 as Value from mytable
 union 
 select name2, value2 from mytable
 union 
 select name3, value3 from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks! scaisEdge.. Your saved my day..

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query..

```
  Select name1 Name,value1 Value from YourTable 
   Union all
    Select name2 ,value2 from YourTable 
     Union all
      Select name3 ,value3 from YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Unnikrishman R..

Answer (score 0):

Temp Table Method in case union all performs slow or just to show an alternative....

```
DECLARE @Table as TABLE (name1 CHAR(1), name2 CHAR(1), name3 CHAR(1), value1 INT, value2 INT, value3 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A','B','C',1,2,3)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TempTable
    END

SELECT name1 as Name, value1 as Value
INTO #TempTable
FROM
    @Table

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT name2, value2
FROM
    @Table

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT name3, value3
FROM
    @Table

SELECT * 
FROm
    #TempTable
```